# Regarding the python module symtable

Tags: python

I'm working on a plugin which is sort of a class browser for python codes. I found the python module *symtable* helpful. However, it seems that the module has a drawback. I cannot get instance attributes using this module. Here's an example python code in a file named *src.py*:

```
import os

class A():
    cl_attr = 1
    def fn1(self):
        self.attr1 = 'hello'
    def fn2(self, arg):
        self.attr2 = arg
```

Then in the python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Jul  9 2010, 09:28:49) 
[GCC 4.1.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> src = open('src.py', 'r').read()
>>> import symtable
>>> table = symtable.symtable(src, 'src.py', 'exec')
>>> table.get_children()[0].get_identifiers()
['fn1', 'cl_attr', 'fn2']
```

The above results indicate that the class attribute `cl_attr` is returned. However, when I try:

```
>>> table.get_children()[0].get_children()[0].get_identifiers()
['self']
>>> table.get_children()[0].get_children()[1].get_identifiers()
['self', 'arg']
```

I can only get the arguments of the instance methods, while the instance attributes are missing.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a way to get the instance attributes. If not, I have to resort to another python module *ast*. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`symtable` executes the code given to it, but it does not instantiate your class `A`. So it follows the interpreter through defining the class `A`, with its methods, but the analysis of methods is *static* - methods are not actually executed, because the class is not actually instantiated. Another way to understand it - the `symtable` shows information gathered during *compilation* of Python code to bytecode.

The `ast` module may help you here, but also won't help in the general case; because Python is so dynamic, new attributes can be added to objects at runtime, with even their names being constructed from user input - static analysis with tools like `symtable` and `ast` can't discover all such methods. You need to actually run the code with proper hooks to capture your information.

Comment: Thanks! It is quite informative. But I think `ast` is enough for me. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @user2346069: `ast` should be enough for most realistic use-cases